# How to pass parameters from shiny ui object to a server render object

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a shiny dashboard and am making many plots from the same dataset. Instead of making separate server output$name objects for each series that I select, I would like to have one server object with a variable and then pass a variable to each ui object that indicates which series I want it to display.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
    fluidRow(

      column(width = 6,
        box(title = "Net Income", width=NULL,
          dygraphOutput(outputId = "net_income", height = "300px"))
             ),

       column(width = 6,
         box(title = "Accounts Receivable", width=NULL,
            dygraphOutput(outputId = "accounts", height = "300px"))
              )  
) # end ui
```

Notice the multiple server objects that I'm creating that chooses the series to display from a single object, fcast_data. I'm displaying 10 charts from this dataset, so would have to produce 10 separate server render objects. I would like to create 1 server object with a variable 'series_name' that I could pass from the ui objects to indicate which series I want to display.

```
server <- function(input, output) { 
  output$net_income <- renderDygraph({ 
    dygraph(fcast_data %>% select(net_income), group = "my_dash")})

  output$accounts_receivable <- renderDygraph({ 
     dygraph(fcast_data %>% select(accounts_receivable), group = "my_dash")})

} # end server
```

Is there a way that I can make one server object (renderDygraph) that just takes parameters from my ui object (dygraphOutput) to choose different series to display? I know how to do this using selectInputs, but can't figure out how to hard-code variables in the ui object to pass to server.

Comment: Pass the column names in your select functions to a `selectInput()` function in your UI.  Then pass the string to a single plot - you may need to convert to `select_()` given the quotations from the input string.

Comment: this might be of interest: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/creating-a-ui-from-a-loop.html

Comment: @BigDataScientist Yes, this very much interests me :) I think this is likely exactly what I need. I'll play with this. Thanks!

Comment: @RyanMorton does the selectInput() object always display in the ui, though? I'll try this and see whether I can use selectInput() without display any kind of ui select element, as I don't want any user input available.

Comment: @BigDataScientist OMG, yes. This is totally what I needed. Many thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sake of completeness: like I mentioned in the comment, an example can be found here:
https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/creating-a-ui-from-a-loop.html.

Without being able to test it with the given code, it would be something along the lines of this:

```
types <- c("net_income", "accounts_receivable")

# server
lapply(1:2, function(nr) {
  output[[paste0("dy_g", nr)]] <- renderDygraph({ 
    dygraph(fcast_data %>% select(get(types[nr])), group = "my_dash")
  })
}

# ui
lapply(1:2, function(nr) {
  column(width = 6,
         box(title = types[nr], width=NULL,
             dygraphOutput(outputId = paste0("dy_g", nr), height = "300px"))
  )
})
```

Comment: Nailed it. I implemented this yesterday. Solved all my problems. Thanks, again!